# Python Beautifulsoup get tags under another tag (from selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am using `Selenium` to do web scraping and would like to instead use `beautiful soup`, but I am new to this library, I wanna get all company names and the time and jump to the next page.

Please find my codes using `selenium` first:

```
driver.get('http://www.csisc.cn/zbscbzw/isinbm/index_list_code.shtml')
while True:
    links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="sibian"]/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/a')]
    for link in links:
        driver.get(link)
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        windows = driver.window_handles
        driver.switch_to.window(windows[-1])              
        time = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="con_bj"]/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/publishtime').text
        company = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="title_A"]').text
        driver.back()
    if(len(links)< 20):
      break
```

I tried doing the same with `beautifulsoup` as:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html='http://www.csisc.cn/zbscbzw/isinbm/index_list_code.shtml'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for link in soup.find_all('td'):
    num=link.find('a').get('href')
    print(num)
```

But I get nothing and stuck with the first step.

Could you please help with that?

Comment: When using `BeautifulSoup`, I don't see that you are making a request to the website, how are you passing the HTML to `BeautifulSoup`? Where in your code are you using the `requests` module?

Comment: Hi, guess not, just with these lines in my codes, as I am not familiar with ```BeautifulSoup```, not sure how to use ```requests```

Answer (score 3):

you are not making a request. You are thinking that BeautifulSoup is a HTTPRequest library, it is just a parser. Think of `driver.get()` as `requests.get()` (yes i know they are not the same, but it is for an easier understanding). You need to do something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html_link='http://www.csisc.cn/zbscbzw/isinbm/index_list_code.shtml'
html = requests.get(html_link).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for link in soup.find_all('td'):
    num=link.find('a').get('href')
    print(num)
```

This will allow you to further debug your code. This *MAY NOT* work as some sites require specific headers or automatically reject your request, such as a `user-agent` header. Requests is a very easy (subjective of course) library to work with and has a lot of support on this site. To save some head-scratching I will go ahead and tell you that if the site requires javascript, Selenium or some variant is the best option.

Comment: Thanks Noah, so does it mean if I wanna scrap things, click pages , beautifulsoup cannot achieve that, it only parse the website?

Comment: you do not "click" pages with any sort of HTTP library. When a button is clicked typically, a request is fired off, that request is what you simulate with HTTP libraries like requests.